# Why const char * function is prefered over template<int size> const char (&arr)[]

Tags: c++

I have a Variant class that has string constructors. And I am trying to introduce variant type for string literals - to keep the pointer to source literal without copying it. If I remove the const char * constructor, than my new constructor is called:

```
Variant v = "asdf";
....

template <int size>
Variant(const char (&c_str) [size])
```

But I need the const char * constructor too - not all my stings are literals. And when there is such constructor, my new constructor becomes unreachable code.
Can somebody explain me why?
Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Actually this doesn't help in my case, because currently it's used mainly with constructor syntax.
It may work if I use template instead of const char *.

Comment: This works:

    template <typename ConstCharPtr, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<ConstCharPtr, const char*>::value > >
    Variant(ConstCharPtr sz)